# Conexión a bases de datos

Tags: python, python-3.x, base-de-datos

Deberia usar la misma conexión iniciada con mysql.connector(o cualquier otro conector a base de datos de diferentes lenguajes) para manejar todas la rutas ?
¿O crear una nueva, por cada peticion o ruta?
AYUDAAAAAAA

```py
from flask import Flask
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
     mycursor.execute("alguna cosulta")
     return "Hello World!"

@app.route("/algo")
    def hello():
        mycursor.execute("alguna otro consulta")
        return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Eso estaria correcto supongamos en produccion?
O lo correcto es tratar una conexion a la base de datos de forma independiente en cada ruta?

Comment: Hola leroi, sería mejor si pudieras pegar un poco de código o explicar más tu consulta, así como lo pones no se entiende muy bien

Comment: Disculpa por la pereza . Listo acabo de añadir codigo